# nunit console is not telling what tests got failed

Tags: unit-testing, build, nunit, nant

I recently moved out of nunit tag and moved to exec tag to run nunit console for running unit tests.

Here is what i have in my build script:

exec program="nunit-console.exe" verbose="true" failonerror="true">
arg file="../abc.dll"/>
exec>

Here is what I see in output:

task name="exec">250.0064250.0064

As you can see it did run from the duration and I know that my tests are currently failing but my build didn't fail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an example of the exec tag you are now using, please? Also, why are you moving from using the nunit tag?

Comment: Yeah i just did on the top.Because it is not working with .net framework 4 and lots of people have moved from using nunit tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171142/invalid-element-nunit2-unknown-task-or-datatype

Comment: **@alice7:** You moved away from `<nunit>` task and that is a good thing. I know `<exec>` task gives a meaningful output as well since it works for us. I will check this tomorrow. Nevertheless a code sample would be helpful.

Comment: Oh I see - thanks. I'm still on VS 2008 and .Net 3.5 and nunit2 tag is working so can't really help. BTW if you use the Code Sample button when editing your answer Stack Overflow will leave your XML examples alone.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest: I'm clueless. We're executing NUnit console through NAnt's `<exec>` task, we're getting meaningful output and we're absolutely not doing anything fancy:

```
<exec program="C:\dev\tools\NUnit\2.5.9\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console.exe">
  <arg file="C:\foo\bar.dll" />
</exec>
```